# Creating a PHP array for display in an HTML table

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have  database that records the IP address and session ID of users that hit my web-site. I want to display an HTML table of the top ten occuring IP addresses and the number of distinct sessions associated with each IP address.

So I start with this query:

`$sql="SELECT ip, country, city, COUNT(*) as count FROM Hits GROUP BY ip ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10";`

and then, for each of the resulting 10 rows I use a while loop to query the same database to extract the number of distinct session ID's associated with each address thus:

`$sql="SELECT DISTINCT Session FROM Hits WHERE ip='$ipaddress'"`

My challenge is to build, as I go through the while loop, an array (with the same structure as a MySQLi query result) on which I can subsequently use a foreach loop to output an HTML table. Here's my full code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbase");
$sql="SELECT ip, country, city, COUNT(*) as count FROM Hits GROUP BY ip ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $ipaddress = $row["ip"];
     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT Session FROM Hits WHERE ip='$ipaddress'";
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $distinctsessions = mysqli_num_rows($res);
     $data[] =$ipaddress.",".$distinctsessions;
};
$colNames = array_keys(reset($data));
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($colNames as $colName) {
    echo "<td>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
    }   
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_free_result($res);
mysqli_close($con);
```

I realise that my mistake lies in the line:

`$data[] =$ipaddress.",".$distinctsessions;`

and that this probably isn't the correct structure but I can't work out what is. Grateful for advice.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: your data not contains colName key name

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp   -  this may help you

Comment: use $data[] = ['ip' => $ip, 'dist' => $dist]; and remove second foreach in table and use simple $row['ip'] - $row['dist']

Comment: @daremachine Thanks. I've tried the `['ip' => $ip, 'dist' => $dist]` format you suggest but to no avail. I didn't remove the second foreach because I don't understand how that helps. You say that my $data array does not contain the $colName keys but I thought that `$colNames = array_keys(reset($data));` created an array containing the keys (now set to `ip` and `dist`) which `foreach($colNames as $colName) {
    echo "<td>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
    }` would then act on. I'm a newbie so forgive me if I'm wrong and please help me to understand.

Comment: Oh.. I've just realised what you mean by removing the second foreach so I've tried that and I've inserted `foreach ($data as $row) {
 echo "<tr><td>$row['ip']</td><td>$row['dist']</td></tr>";
};` but I'm afraid I get a 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Also tried `echo "<tr><td>".$row['ip']."</td><td>".$row['dist']."</td></tr>";` but still doesn't work.

Comment: what you want to show in your html?

Comment: I fixed it. Made a simple syntax error and now working. Thanks to all especially @daremachine.

Comment: why r u not achiving this by using one single query?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `foreach` use below code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbase");
$sql="SELECT ip, country, city, COUNT(*) as count FROM Hits GROUP BY ip ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $ipaddress = $row["ip"];
     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT Session FROM Hits WHERE ip='$ipaddress'";
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $distinctsessions = mysqli_num_rows($res);
 ?>
     <tr>
          <td><?php echo $ipaddress; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $distinctsessions; ?></td>
     </tr>
  <?php }
         echo "</table>";
         mysqli_free_result($result);
         mysqli_free_result($res);
         mysqli_close($con); 
  ?>
```